# Create Self Signed Certificate with Subject Key Identifier

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I want to create a self signed certificate with RSA algorithm keysize 2048 with subject key identifier. I know we made some some default change in `openssl.conf`. What i suppose to change?

```
genrsa -des3 -out mcedt.key 2048
req -new -key mcedt.key -out mcedt.csr
CN = server.test , OU =, O =, L = Toronto, S = ontario , C = can
x509 -req -days 365 -in mcedt.csr -signkey mcedt.key -out mcedt.crt
pkcs12 -export -in mcedt.crt -inkey mcedt.key -out mcedt.pfx
```

Comment: Hello, I see you've been working with MCEDT. Did you get it to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl). Ensure `subjectKeyIdentifier = hash` is in the `[x509_ext]` area of the CONF file. You should include an authority key identifier, too. For that, `authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer`.

Answer (score 8):

You could create an extension file (extensions.cnf) with the following information:

```
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
```

as mentioned by OpenSSL :

> This is really a string extension and can take two possible values.
>   Either the word hash which will automatically follow the guidelines in
>   RFC3280 or a hex string giving the extension value to include. The use
>   of the hex string is strongly discouraged.

Then you should change

```
x509 -req -days 365 -in mcedt.csr -signkey mcedt.key -out mcedt.crt
```

into

```
x509 -req -days 365 -extfile extensions.cnf -in mcedt.csr -signkey mcedt.key -out mcedt.crt
```

Comment: hi, by default in OpenSSL.conf file having the extension. isn't it?

Comment: Yes you could use the default one from OpenSSL and uncomment/modify what you need as extension then pass its path as the filename. But I suggest you better to have your own or a copy of the OpenSSL one.

Comment: BTW if it works just accept the answer so that other people will know that its working :)