# how to generate certificate using openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to generate certificate, which are self signed, using openssl command-line.
Certificate includes authority key identifier & subject key identifier. What I understand is certificate may (or may not)have authority key identifier & subject key identifier. Is it possible to generate without or without authority key identifier & subject key identifier using openssl command-line?
So, I want to generate certificates like the following:

1. Include authority key identifier & subject key identifier. They are the same value.
2. Include difference authority key identifier & subject key identifier. They are not the same value.
3. Not include authority key identifier & include subject key identifier.
   I couldn't find any options to modify them. Please, check it.
   Thanks and Regards,
   Jang.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Self Signed Certificate with Subject Key Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179132/create-self-signed-certificate-with-subject-key-identifier)

Comment: It makes no sense for a self-signed certificate to have an authority key identifier and subject key identifier which differ from each other - if both extensions are present, they should be identical.